# Trashy argument when passing by value C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new here and I need some help in C++ with SFML(2.1). I have written Ctext class, which contains sf::Font and sf::Text and display text according to its position and other parameters.

```
private:
    sf::Font m_font; 
    string m_napis; 
    sf::Text m_text; 
public:
    Ctext(string napis, const unsigned text_size = 30);
    Ctext(const char* napis = ""); // ctor
```

...

```
    Ctext::Ctext(string napis, const unsigned text_size) :
    m_napis(napis)
{
    m_font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"); 
    m_text = sf::Text(m_napis, m_font, text_size);
}

    Ctext::Ctext(const char* napis) :
        m_napis(napis)
    {
        m_font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf");
        m_text = sf::Text(m_napis, m_font, 30);
    }
```

This class works. I have also created another class, which contains Ctext object.

```
private:
    ... 
    Ctext m_title; 
    ...
public:
    Ccurtain(const Ctext title = "");
    ~Ccurtain();
```

...

```
Ccurtain::Ccurtain(const Ctext title) :
m_title(title)
{

}
```

The problem is when I try to create Ccurtain. Everything is fine when:

```
Ctext x = "Exp";    
Ccurtain object(x);
```

.. but I have no idea why I get trash inside Ccurtain constructor when:

```
Ccurtain object("Exp");
```

I wish Ctext was created by passing only "Exp". I know that sf::Font must be kept in memory so I expect default copy constructor to copy it to m_title in Ccurtain. It works only after creating Ctext variable and I don't know why it doesn't when passing "Exp".

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Does it also work for `Ctext x("Exp"); Ccurtain object(x);` or for `Ccurtain object(Ctext("Exp"))`? Maybe you can add the code for the assignment operator= of Ctext for `char*`

Comment: Ccurtain object(Ctext("Exp")); doesn't work. Only Ctext x("Exp") and Ccurtain object(x) works.

Comment: @Gombat `Ctext x = "Exp";` doesn't call the assignment operator.

Comment: Is `sf::Text` implemented by you? What does it do with `m_napis`? Does it store a reference to it?

Comment: @TartanLlama. You are right, Since there is a constructor accepting `char*`, right? @Bocho: What exactly is trash in the constructor of Ccurtain? The string m_napis or what?

Comment: @Gombat no, that form is never assignment because a `Ctext` object doesn't exist yet, so there's nothing to assign to.

Comment: sf::Text is provided by SFML and as far as I know it needs sf::Font and string to work properly. m_napis is just a text which I want to be displayed- I give it to sf::Text which do all the work.

@Gombat There is more data I pass to Ccurtain but I didn't paste it here(it is passed properly). I mean that Ctext parameter seems to be allocated, but not initialized- just like after "new". m_napis is empty.